# android rating bar shows only int values

Tags: android, decimal, ratingbar

I use this code to show a decimal value by a rating bar. but it round the value and show first bigger int

```
    ratingBar.setNumStars(5);
    ratingBar.setMax(5);
    ratingBar.setStepSize(0.5f);
    ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("2.5"));
```

in XML file

```
                            <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:max="5"
                            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                            android:numStars="5"
                            android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

[the image I see in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY3C0.png)

Comment: The code works for me. Could you provide your xml file?

Comment: Try setting rating as:
ratingBar.setRating(2.5f);

Comment: Even after the XML it works well in my studio! Could attach your result in a form of an image?

Comment: @MeghaMainar  It didn't answer. I see three stars colored yet.

Comment: @technicalpo I have just exprienced an issue with Android Studio of not updating Content. Could you remove the application from device and rebuild it!

Comment: @smit I removed the app from the emulator and after rebuilding the app in android studio, installed it again. But it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout:

```
    <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingbar"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:numStars="5" 
android:stepSize="0.5"/>
```

Activity:

```
private RatingBar ratingBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    assert ratingBar != null;

    dosomething();
    ratingBar.setRating(0.0f);
}

private void dosomething() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ratingBar.setRating(2.5f);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Result in a form Image:
[image]

Comment: It didn't work :-( . in My application I update the rating bar a few seconds after oncreate is called (Once the data from server is arrived ). can it be relevant to my problem?

Comment: @technicalpo Oh that is the case. Could you put this `<RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"/>` in your layout file and then do the setting when you have the value. i.e after you have gotten a value from server.

Comment: I did it and no answer yet. It's really strange. I've used ratingBar a couple of times in different applications and in any case faced a problem like this.

Comment: Hold wan't answer as well . It's really strange.

Comment: @technicalpo can you check if it is working on another versions like (22 or 23) ?

Answer (score 0):

I test your code in `sdk 23` and have same problem . I can't figure out way this append but you can temporarily solve it by set rounded value before set the `float` .like this :

```
  ratingBar.setRating(Math.round( 2.5f));
  ratingBar.setRating( 2.5f);
```

also don't set `setMax` just `setStepSize`. let me know if it worked.